# jQuery JSON issue - Repeating images in .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm just having trouble with getting this device to display the images properly: http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/vxpMRJ

You can see that the same image is repeated for every object instance.

The JS looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON("http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/ZevNgX.js", function(data) {

        $.each(data,function(i,data){

 $('#vdResult').append('<div class="vdListing"><div class="vdListimg">'+'</div>'+'<div class="vdListinf"><div class="vdInftit"><h4>'+data.name+'</h4></div><div class="vdInfurl"><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="'+data.url+'">View Site ></a></div><div class="vdInfinf"><div class="vdInfcol vL"><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Country:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.country+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Region:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.region+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Shipping:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.shipping+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Payments:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.payment+'</div></div></div><div class="vdInfcol vC"><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">New Guitars:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.newGuitars+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Used Guitars:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.usedGuitars+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Vintage Guitars:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.vintageGuitars+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Location:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.shop+'</div></div></div><div class="vdInfcol vR"><div class="vdItem spec"><div class="spTit">Specialties:</div><div class="spRes">'+data.specialty+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="spTit">Website Quality:</div><div class="spRes qual">'+data.quality+'</div></div></div></div></div></div>');

            $('.vdListimg').css('background-image','url(https://www.electricherald.com/shopDir/img/' + data.image + '.jpg)');

        });


$(function(){
    $(".splitR").each(function(){
      var content = $(this).text()
          if (content == '') { 
            $(this).parent().css('color','#ccc')
            $(this).text('No')
          }
    });
    $(".spRes").each(function(){
      var content = $(this).text()
          if (content == '') { 
            $(this).parent().hide()
          }
    });
});

});

});
```

Particularly, the issue is with this line:

```
        $('.vdListimg').css('background-image','url(https://www.electricherald.com/shopDir/img/' + data.image + '.jpg)');
```

All the other elements are created individually just fine, so I'm wondering why this one is calling the same field for every instance in spite of being in the .each function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Because you are changing the background to all elements with vdListImg class. Let me a second I am fixing your code.

Comment: You should be careful when using the same variable name in two places `$.each(data, function (i, data) { // what does data refer to here?`. Better to use a different name for the anonymous function's parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing only with the problematic code:

```js
$.getJSON("http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/ZevNgX.js", function(result) {

      $.each(result, function(i, data) {

        $('#vdResult').append('<div class="vdListing"><div class="vdListimg">' + '</div>' + '<div class="vdListinf"><div class="vdInftit"><h4>' + data.name + '</h4></div><div class="vdInfurl"><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="' + data.url + '">View Site ></a></div><div class="vdInfinf"><div class="vdInfcol vL"><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Country:</div><div class="splitR">' + data.country + '</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Region:</div><div class="splitR">' + data.region + '</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Shipping:</div><div class="splitR">' + data.shipping + '</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Payments:</div><div class="splitR">' + data.payment + '</div></div></div><div class="vdInfcol vC"><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">New Guitars:</div><div class="splitR">' + data.newGuitars + '</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Used Guitars:</div><div class="splitR">' + data.usedGuitars + '</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Vintage Guitars:</div><div class="splitR">' + data.vintageGuitars + '</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Location:</div><div class="splitR">' + data.shop + '</div></div></div><div class="vdInfcol vR"><div class="vdItem spec"><div class="spTit">Specialties:</div><div class="spRes">' + data.specialty + '</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="spTit">Website Quality:</div><div class="spRes qual">' + data.quality + '</div></div></div></div></div></div>');

        $('#vdResult').find('.vdListimg').last().css('background-image', 'url(https://www.electricherald.com/shopDir/img/' + data.image + '.jpg)');

      });
```

Note the `last()` call, which gets that item with that class which was added last, so that the CSS only applies to that. Note I renamed the initial `data` argument to remove the variable shadowing.

Comment: You've done the best job keeping my original (shitty) code intact so I can keep working with it :]

Comment: I'll have to start using .find more because it seems like it could solve a lot more issues of mine..

Answer (score 2):

You are updating all background images at the same time by using -   $('.vdListimg') selector.
I have made correction in your code

```
     $.each(data,function(i,data){  
          var i = data;
          var $div = $("<div>", {"class": "vdListing"});
          $div.html('<div class="vdListimg">'+'</div>'+'<div class="vdListinf"><div class="vdInftit"><h4>'+i.name+'</h4></div><div class="vdInfurl"><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="'+data.url+'">View Site ></a></div><div class="vdInfinf"><div class="vdInfcol vL"><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Country:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.country+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Region:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.region+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Shipping:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.shipping+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Payments:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.payment+'</div></div></div><div class="vdInfcol vC"><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">New Guitars:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.newGuitars+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Used Guitars:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.usedGuitars+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Vintage Guitars:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.vintageGuitars+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="splitL">Location:</div><div class="splitR">'+data.shop+'</div></div></div><div class="vdInfcol vR"><div class="vdItem spec"><div class="spTit">Specialties:</div><div class="spRes">'+data.specialty+'</div></div><div class="vdItem"><div class="spTit">Website Quality:</div><div class="spRes qual">'+data.quality+'</div></div></div></div></div>');
          $div.find('.vdListimg').css('background-image','url(https://www.electricherald.com/shopDir/img/' + i.image + '.jpg)');

          $('#vdResult').append($div);



            $("input[name='newGuitars']").change(function(){
                 if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                   if(data.newGuitars != 'Yes'){}
                 $("h2").css('color','red')
                 }else{
                          $("h2").css('color','black')
                  }
      });

    });
```

Here I have created a new 'div' on the fly with class "vdListing". Then added html to it. Later on I searched the image with class - "vdListimg" specific to that "div.vdListing" and made changes to its background image.
Let me know in case of any issues

Comment: I like this solution because it allows me to apply the image as a background still rather than changing it to a regular image element - my purpose in doing that is so I can scale the images with the divs in-between media queries (that I haven't gotten to yet). Thanks very much!

Comment: Try to use jquery to add elements as even a single miss - like a comma can break your code. it will help you in long run

Answer (score 1):

With setting your background image using a CSS class the very last image is getting applied to *all* of your image containers.

A possible solution would be to use the images directly, not as a background:

```
<div class="vdListimg"><img src="https://www.electricherald.com/shopDir/img/' + data.image + '.jpg"></div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMvjNq)

Answer (score 1):

You should set it directly in the html like this.

```
<div class="vdListimg" style="background-image: url(https://www.electricherald.com/shopDir/img/' + data.image + '.jpg);">'+'</div>
```

Comment: this is incorrect.. all the containers are created, but having the same className they are set the same BG image on each step - and the image is always the current one

Comment: You'r right! But it still works! And he does not have to redo his styling.

Comment: it sure does :) because every container now has its *own* background, instead of one image applied to all containers